# NaOH etching time and temperature for Stainless Steels (SS-304) for Surface Preparation for coating

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, kinetics, materials, solid-state-chemistry

To improve adhesion of TiO2 coatings on stainless steel sample I am treating SS-304 with 1M NaOH for functionalizing the surface with metal hydroxide groups as well as increasing roughness. What would be the general range of temperature of NaOH solution we required and duration of this process.